# Как лучше хранить массив пользователей онлайн на golang?

Tags: golang, websocket

Как лучше хранить массив пользователей онлайн?
Пользователи подключаются по websocket.
Есть слайсы со следующими структурами

```
Users {Id,Name .....}  
SocketsOnline{Id, *webSocketType, (UserId)}   
UsersOnline{UserId,map [SocketId]}  
Rooms{Id,NameRoom}  
SocketsInRoom{RoomId,SocketId} //или UserId вместо сокета
```

когда подключается пользователь- создаётся соккет и заносится в слайс из типа SocketsOnline.
Если нужно разослать сообщение всем- я перебираю весь слайс и отсылаю сообщение всем.
Но я хочу параллельно хранить указатели на сокеты у каждого пользователя типа UsersOnline.
Тоесть когда подключился сокет 1- я знаю, что это пользователь id333 -я создаю объект в слайсе типа UsersOnline и хочу кинуть ссылку на сокет 1.
Если подкл сокет 2, пользователь id333 - я добавляю ещё.
Если пользователь отключился- я удаляю сокет из SocketsOnline и всё норм.
Поидее- если создать указатели на сокеты у пользователя, то при удалении из SocketsOnline он должен исчезнуть в UsersOnline.
Но если отключается сокет, то сам UserOnline не удалится. (Как это подчищать?)
Вопрос собственно- как это реализовать?  или,может,-нужна другая логика?

Comment: Я не работал с golang, но в данном вопросе, как я понимаю, это и не имеет значения. Хотелось бы спросить следующее... А зачем у Вас отдельный слайс для сокетов и айдишников? Почему нельзя хранить все в useronline? Что должно быть ключом в таком случае - решать Вам - зависит от того, с чем Вы чаще работаете (к чему чаще происходит обращение). Скорее всего это айдишники пользователей. А накладных расходов на поиск соответствующего сокета в слайсе я бы не боялся. Не думаю, что они настолько будут велики.

Comment: @"Max ZS" я до этого так и делал- всё в одном слайсе. Допустим- надо разослать всем- я просто перебираю всех и отсылаю-всё норм. А если отослать определённому юзеру или группе юзеров?....конечно можно так-же перебирать всех и сравнивать, но это вроде как-то не очень производительно. Вот я и думаю-держать ещё несколько видов слайсов- например- пользователи в комнате для чата и пользователи вообще. Тоесть тогда не перебирал бы всех и искал бы там айди пользователи и рассылал ему, а взял бы непосредственно слайс этого пользователя и разослал конкретно его подключениям

Comment: Я только из своего опыта могу сказать, что на том же с++ затраты на поиск в итоге не очень и велики оказывались. Поэтому и предлагаю не смотреть в данном случае на производительность. Есть правда одно небольшое "но"... Я использовал для этого контейнеры (по Вашему, читай, слайсы), где ключи отсортированы изначально. Т.е. при вставке записи она в контейнере помещается сразу "по алфавиту". Поэтому в последующем уже в работе поиск сокета, зная id (который он является ключом), довольно не накладен.

Comment: Т.е. основные затраты идут при вставке в такой контейнер. Но это разовая операция для каждой записи. А последующая работа с записью очень и очень не разовая. Я все это имею ввиду при условии постоянного подключения пользователей (а не подключился-отключился-подключился-отключился...). Ну а создавать горы контейнеров (слайсов) для каждого отдельного параметра - это не комильфо.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в таких случая используют мапы, задавая ключом идентификатор или указатель на сокет, а значением -- стурктуру с пользователем (либо указатель на нее)

```
make(map[*Socket] *User)
```

Comment: Те кто будут так делать - учитывайте, что использование очень дорого по памяти и вы не сможете хранить много соединений

Answer (score 0):

Работал с немного другой логикой, может Вам подойдет

Для удобной организации работы можно использовать списки ("container/list").
К примеру, можно использовать следующую схему работы с веб сокетами.

```
import (
    "container/list"
)

//Здесь Ваша информация, которую Вы будете хранить

type Subscriber struct {
    Name string //и другая информация
    Conn *websocket.Conn 
}
//Проверка, новый ли пользователь, и если новый, то добавлением его в конец списка пользователей с активным соединением. Для удобства можно использовать каналы

if !isUserExist(subscribers, sub.Name) {
                subscribers.PushBack(sub) // Проверяем, существует ли этот пользователь уже, если нет, то добавляем
}

func isUserExist(subscribers *list.List, user string) bool {
    for sub := subscribers.Front(); sub != nil; sub = sub.Next() {
        if sub.Value.(Subscriber).Name == user {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

С достаточно удобной организацией работы можно ознакомиться здесь: [Чат](https://github.com/beego/samples/tree/master/WebIM)